# Pass data from view to controller to template view to partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So I have a bit of a confusing situation that may just require some serious reorganization of my code, but I'll do my best to explain and if any further clarification or code is needed, I'll be glad to answer any questions.

In one of my views called Clear.cshtml, I have a bunch of text boxes for searching my database of Projects (Project.cs being the primary model for my website). The text boxes are not implemented yet as search boxes, I just have all of the text boxes set up on the page and currently they don't do anything except look good. I also have a button at the top of the page that is supposed to be the search button. It also doesn't do anything yet. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
<button type="button" id="show" class="find-proj">Find Project</button>

<div class="form-vertical">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 entry-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.FirstNamedInsured, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Project.FirstNamedInsured, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project.FirstNamedInsured, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
...etc.
```

`model` in that code is a ViewModel I made called ProjectViewModel.cs. This is what it looks like (pretty simple):

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public IQueryable<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> States { get; set; }

    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

`States` is just to populate a drop-down menu on Clear.cshtml.

I want to use these search boxes to return a list of the Projects in my database that match all of the terms (I want none of the search boxes to be mandatory, but the returned list of Projects should match all of the search boxes that have been filled). I was trying to model my controller after [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search), so this is what the action looks like currently:

```
public ActionResult Clear(string firstNamedInsured)
    {
        var states = GetAllStates();

        var model = new ProjectClearanceApp.Models.ProjectViewModel();

        model.States = GetSelectListItems(states);
        model.Projects = from m in db.Projects select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstNamedInsured))
        {
            model.Projects = model.Projects.Where(s => s.FirstNamedInsured.Contains(firstNamedInsured));
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

I obviously only have one search term in that function, because I hit a wall when I was trying to implement this step-by-step. My partial view is rendered in my _Layout.cshtml at the bottom of the page like so:

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Projects/_ClearedProjects.cshtml")
</div>
```

So basically what I'm trying to is pass the search terms from Clear.cshtml to ProjectController.cs, then pass the list of matching projects to _Layout.cshtml, and then pass the list again from _Layout.cshtml to _ClearedProjects.cshtml. Any advice (on how to implement this, or how to rearrange my code to achieve the same goal) would be much appreciated. Sorry for the long post!

Comment: So, if I understand correctly you have a search box on your footer or similar and when you hit search you want to reload the entire page ?

Comment: @EtienneMermillod No. I have a page of search boxes, and when I hit search I want to reload the footer (which renders the partial view). Re-read my last paragraph. My main goal is turning the search terms into a list of matching projects, and passing that list to the partial view so that I can display them.

Comment: So, if you want to partial refresh your page you have few options: use ajax form, or javascript/jquery to perform an ajax call returning json or some html that will replace the footer.

Comment: Okay that still doesn't answer my question of how to pass the data from view to controller to view.